# Как передать контекст методу openFileOutput()?

Tags: android, context, fileoutputstream

Не могу записать данные в файл, ошибка `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileOutputStream android.content.Context.openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference` в коде:

```
       package mate.files;

import android.content.Context;
import android.icu.util.Output;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class CfgMgr {
    /*Options:
      - Write (Writes the setting to JSON)
      - Read (Returns the setting from JSON)
      - ReCreate (Re-creates a JSON file with default settings)
      - Import (Re-Creates a JSON file and re-writes all settings)
      - Export (Returns all settings)
      - ExportRaw (Returns a JSON file)
      */


    public String ReCreate(Context context) throws IOException {

        //Re-creating a file
        File Cfg = new File("/data/data/mate.files/", "Cfg.json");
        if (!Cfg.exists()) {

            try {
                Cfg.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Cfg.delete();
            try {
                Cfg.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //Filling the file with the settings
        String CfgStr = "\"{\\\"Settings\\\":{\\\"OnStartOpen\\\":\\\"PrevSession\\\",\\\"ExitBehavior\\\":\\\"NoReqNoDeletion\\\",\\\"ExitRequestTimeout\\\":\\\"No\\\",\\\"DefaultAction\\\":\\\"Exit\\\",\\\"Locale\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"Accounts\\\":\\\"No\\\",\\\"ListViewMode\\\":\\\"DetailedList\\\",//ПланируетсяулучшениекастомизациирежимаDetailedList.\\\"ListSort\\\":\\\"AZ\\\",\\\"ShowGraphAboveList\\\":false,\\\"UITheme\\\":\\\"Space\\\",\\\"TabBar\\\":\\\"Top\\\",\\\"TabCloseBtn\\\":\\\"Left\\\",\\\"TabIcon\\\":false,\\\"NewTabPos\\\":\\\"AfterCurrent\\\",\\\"ClonedTabPos\\\":\\\"AfterCurrent\\\",\\\"MinActiveTabWidth\\\":\\\"65px\\\",\\\"MinTabWidth\\\":\\\"45px\\\",\\\"MaxActiveTabWidth\\\":\\\"MaxPossible\\\",\\\"MaxTabWidth\\\":\\\"MaxPossible\\\",\\\"TabShape\\\":\\\"Rounded\\\",\\\"TabMark\\\":\\\"Line\\\",\\\"TabMarkColor\\\":\\\"DefinedByTheme\\\",\\\"TabMarkWeight\\\":\\\"8px\\\",\\\"ShowTabCloseBtnOn\\\":\\\"AllTabs\\\",\\\"NewTabBtnPos\\\":\\\"Right\\\",\\\"EnableExperimentalTabFeatures\\\":false,//Экспериментальныефункции-перемещениеигруппировкавкладок.\\\"EnableTabGrouping\\\":true,\\\"TabGroupType\\\":\\\"Compact\\\",\\\"GroupTabsByDrag\\\":\\\"false\\\",\\\"OpenTabGroupAppearance\\\":\\\"Dropdn\\\",\\\"Layout1SelectonBottom\\\":\\\"NormBarPinned\\\",\\\"Layout1SelectionBottomContent\\\":\\\"IconPlusNewDeleteCopyPasteCompressMenu\\\",\\\"Layout1SelectionBottomAppearance\\\":\\\"RoundedWeight30px\\\"}}\"";
        try {

//ПРОБЛЕМА:

            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("Cfg.json", MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(CfgStr);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Не удалось записать настройки. Вызвано исключение ввода-вывода.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Из ошибки я понял, что надо как-то передать методу контекст, но как? Чтобы работало?

Comment: Не понятен вопрос, что значит как передать контекст в метод? Да как угодно. У вас нулевой объект выкидывает причем тут контекст. Скорее всего у вас нет прав создавать файл по данному пути.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `Activity` является потомком `android.content.Context` - соответственно его можно использовать везде, где нужен контекст.
В самом классе активности вы можете использовать специальную ссылку "на себя"  `this`:

```java
    new OutputStreamWriter(this.openFileOutput("Cfg.json", MODE_PRIVATE));
```

При вызове метода предка java разрешает ссылку `this` и вовсе опустить:

```java
    new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("Cfg.json", MODE_PRIVATE));
```

В другой класс следует передавать ссылку на контекст и вызывать метод на этой ссылке. Вы вроде как уже передаёте её параметром метода и вызов должен выглядеть так:

```java
new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("Cfg.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
```

Comment: Это не работает

Comment: Это мне ни о чём не говорит. Подробности? Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: Всё та же ошибка, что и была.

Comment: В таком виде у вас код вообще не должен компилироваться, не то что запускаться. Я написал что так можно делать в классе-наследнике `Activity`, а не в каком попало. См. обновлённый ответ

Comment: У меня вот как:

Теперь, если я допишу extends Activity, то передаваемый контекст подчёркивается красным, с тем методом всё ок. А если без наследования Активити, то контекст передаётся, а в методе MODE_PRIVATE выделено красным.

Comment: `extends Activity` дописывать бессмысленно - контекст получает только тот экземпляр активности, который запущен системой (через ярлык юзером или программно через `startActivity()`). `MODE_PRIVATE` - константа из всё того же класса `android.content.Context`. Нужно либо импортировать её статически, либо указать класс: `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`

Comment: А теперь подчёркивется ```Context context``` при передаче его в класс. Что за... ?

Comment: Учебник по азам java вам надо почитать... Если IDE что-то подчёркивает, то наверное же и причину пишет, и даже варианты решения предлагает иногда. Либо класс не импортирован, либо не туда написано, что-то лишнее, чего-то не хватает - при знаниях основ синтаксиса языка таких проблем у вас не должно возникать